# Output is incorrect from a math equation with-in java, For the first person and second

Tags: java

When I enter the total amount of tips into the JOptionPane that I have for getting the tips, it will just reprint what I have entered for a jOptionPane on the first person. Even though the math equation is using the rate variable that you get when you divide the total hours by the total tips. The last person calculate by the program is always correct but any of the others is incorrect. I'm not sure what could be causing this to happen I have tried all I know to fix this and I have not found any information online to help me out. I'm using NetBeans to create the gui and I have plug-in my code for each button

```
private void getHoursActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DecimalFormat monn = new DecimalFormat( "0.00" );

        hourss = blake += barker += kevin += pierce += sam += dolphy += johnC += johnD += slut += tanner += ray += trevor += zachB += zachW += petty += mikey += mitch += marge += mattB += kolb += kyle += jackson += clinton += cody += cam += bailey += bMart += addison;

       tip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Total Amount Of Tips?" );

       tips = Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf( tip ) );

       String th = String.valueOf( hourss );

           double hh = Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf(hourss) );

       totalHoursJTextField.setText( th );

       Rate = tips / hh;

           rateJTextField.setText( String.valueOf(monn.format(Rate) ) );

           test1.setText( bp );
           test2.setText( kev );
           test3.setText( bar );
    }                                        

    private void calcBnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       




    }                                      

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String rrate = rateJTextField.getText();
        double ff = Double.parseDouble( rrate );

        br2 = barker * ff;
        kv2 = kevin * ff;
        bp2 = ff * blake;
        pk = pierce * ff;

        test.setText( tip );

        output.append( "\n" + "Barker" + "\t" + br2 + "\n" + "--------------------" );
        output.append( "\n" + "Kevin" + "\t" + kv2 + "\n" + "--------------------" );
        output.append( "\n" + "Blake" + "\t" + bp2 + "\n" + "--------------------" );
        output.append( "\n" + "Pierce" + "\t" + pk + "\n" + "--------------------" );
```

[image: Picture showing the output and the rate and total hours.]

Comment: The line `hourss = blake += barker += kevin += pierce ... += bMart += addison;` looks very strange. What do you want to do with this line of code?

Comment: @Thomas Kläger that uses all the buttons as in the picture. So when the JOptionPane pops up you enter the hours that they work and then I convert the input into a double and the names like blake barker ect I add all of those with the += to get my total overall hours for the day.

Comment: Yes, but: you are not only adding up the hours. You add the hours of `addison` to those of `bMart` (and `bMart` now contains the sum of those hours), then you add that sum to the hours of `bailey` (and `baily` now contains the sum of the hours of `addison`, `bMart` and `bailey`) and so on. Are you sure that you did not intend to write `hourss = blake + barker + kevin + pierce + ... + bMart + addison`?

Comment: @Thomas Kläger Ah yes that could be some of my issues, would that help when I do the final calculation to get the amount of tips for everyone; so when I display the output of the math correctly. As in the picture you can see somehow blake has more tips than the amount of tips I had entered. The program then seems to work down from that number for some reason; how would that be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
hourss = blake += barker += kevin += pierce; // rest omitted
```

Lets start with these values:

```
blake = 3.4; barker = 6.3; kevin = 3.2; pierce = 0;
```

Now if you execute the offending line, you get these values:

```
hourss == 12.9; blake == 12.9; barker == 9.5; kevin == 3.2; pierce == 0;
```

With 230 for `tips`, you get a rate of `17.8294` (rounded to four decimal places), and then

- for blake: `17.83*12.9` (rounded 230.007) instead of `17.8294*3.4` (rounded 60.62)
- for barker: `17.83*9.5` (rounded 169.385) instead of `17.8294*6.3` (rounded 112.33)
- for kevin: `17.83*3.2` (rounded 57.056) instead of `17.8294*3.2` (rounded 57.05)

and if you add together the "instead"-values you get a total of 230...

---

So you definitely should replace the line

```
hourss = blake += barker += kevin += pierce += sam += dolphy += johnC += johnD += slut += tanner += ray += trevor += zachB += zachW += petty += mikey += mitch += marge += mattB += kolb += kyle += jackson += clinton += cody += cam += bailey += bMart += addison;
```

with

```
hourss = blake + barker + kevin + pierce + sam + dolphy + johnC + johnD + slut + tanner + ray + trevor + zachB + zachW + petty + mikey + mitch + marge + mattB + kolb + kyle + jackson + clinton + cody + cam + bailey + bMart + addison;
```

Also you do a awful lot of conversions from `double` to `String` and back, which costs you precision (and performance, but this is currently not the problem).

Comment: Yup that fix the entire math equations issues that I was having, Thanks for your help. Always helps to have a second pair of eyes.